# User defined function which computes mean of specific dataframe rows and replaces them, applied on a list of dataframes

Tags: r

My question actually contains 2 problems:
1. create a user defined function which replaces rows based on condition by their means
2. apply it to a list of dataframes

1st problem:
E.g., when we have the following dataframe:

```
Year Measurement1 Measurement2
2010 5            6
2011 4            2
2011 6            4
2011 2            1
2012 1            4
2012 5            10
2013 6            1
```

I want to create a user defined function, which computes the mean of the rows with the same year (condition) and replaces the rows with the same year by a row with the compueted mean.
(Unfortunately I don't have the same amount of rows for each year.)

For the dataframe:

```
Year Measurement1 Measurement2
2010 5            6
2011 6            3.5
2012 3            7
2013 6            1
```

2nd problem:
If there is a way to create such a user defined function, how do I apply it to a list of dataframes, e.g. created with

```
dfs = Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))
```

I would really appreciate any help!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: check out the `dplyr` package. In particular you want to take a look at `group_by` and `summarise`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you apply it to one dataframe using base R `aggregate`

```
aggregate(cbind(Measurement1, Measurement2)~Year, df, mean)

#  Year Measurement1 Measurement2
#1 2010            5        6.000
#2 2011            4        2.333
#3 2012            3        7.000
#4 2013            6        1.000
```

Now let's assume you want to apply this to list of dataframes (say `list_df`), you can use `lapply`

```
lapply(list_df, function(df) aggregate(cbind(Measurement1, Measurement2)~Year, df, mean))
```

---

If we have multiple columns to `aggregate`, we can create a `formula` object

```
Names <- c("Measurement1", "Measurement2")
aggregate(formula(paste0("cbind(", paste(Names, collapse = " , "), ")~Year")), df, mean)

#  Year Measurement1 Measurement2
#1 2010            5  6.000000000
#2 2011            4  2.333333333
#3 2012            3  7.000000000
#4 2013            6  1.000000000
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution :)
I actually have 72 columns to perform this task on. I therefore created a list ```Names``` with their names ("character") and entered it the following way in your input:
```aggregate(cbind(get(Names))~Year, df, mean)```
Unfortunatly this gives me beside the Year column just one more column as an output.

Comment: @Mcgroger We can create a formula object with it. See my updated answer.

Comment: This gives me the following error:
```Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
 no rows to aggregate```
So it seems like it does calculate the mean but doesn't know in which row to put it in.

Comment: @Mcgroger It means for some of the dataframe in the list there are 0 rows. Can you check what is the output for `any(sapply(list_df, nrow) == 0)` ?

Comment: @ Ronak Shah For ```any(sapply(list_df, nrow) == 0) ``` I get  ```FLASE``` as return.

Comment: What is `length(list_df)` and `sapply(list_df, class)` has all dataframes ?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, use `data.table`:

```
 library(data.table)

 dt <- as.data.table(YourData)
 dt[,.(Measurement1_mean=mean(Measurement1), Measurement2_mean=mean(Measurement2)),by=Year]
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Cettt, you can use `dplyr`

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise(mean1 = mean(M1),mean2 = mean(M2))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
   Year mean1 mean2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2010     5  6   
2  2011     4  2.33
3  2012     3  7   
4  2013     6  1
```

Answer (score 0):

For `base R`, additional to the `aggreate()` solution by @Ronak Shah, you can also use `ave` and `unique()` to make it:

```
unique(with(df,
            data.frame(
              Year = Year,
              Measurement1=ave(Measurement1,Year),
              Measurement2=ave(Measurement2,Year))))
```

which gives:

```
  Year Measurement1 Measurement2
1 2010            5     6.000000
2 2011            4     2.333333
5 2012            3     7.000000
7 2013            6     1.000000
```